# how to display date based on difference in laravel?

Tags: laravel

in table I have start_date and end_date column like this

```
start_date     end_date 
----------    ----------
2023-05-23    2023-05-30
```

how do I make it output like this in laravel

```
2023-05-23
2023-05-24
2023-05-25
2023-05-26
2023-05-27
2023-05-28
2023-05-29
2023-05-30
```

I hope someone can answer my question, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the `range()` method of **Carbon**.

```
$period = now()->parse('2023-05-23')->range('2023-05-30');

foreach($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

`range()` is an alias for [CarbonPeriod](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period).